# Plotting torch.tensor in Pytorch: Invalid dimension error

Tags: matplotlib, pytorch

I have a `torch.Tensor` object and this has the shape of `torch.Size([9, 1, 28, 28]))`.

I tried something like

```
for digit in range(10):
  similar_img = create_interpolates(/*something...*/)
  plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
  plt.imshow(similar_img.detach().numpy())
```

But this gives me: `TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data`

Any help?

Comment: `plt.imshow` expects a two or three dimensional tensor that is being interpreted as image. `plt.imshow(similar_img.detach().numpy()[digit,0])` should help you.

Comment: On the line `plt.imshow(similar_img.detach().numpy()[digit, 0])`, I'm getting `IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9`

Comment: You'll want to loop to 9 instead of 10 (you have nine entries in the first dimension).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code snippet.

```
for digit in range(10):
    similar_img = create_interpolates(/*something...*/)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    plt.imshow(similar_img[digit].numpy().squeeze())
```

Thank you